# pgr_dijkstra returns "invalid memory alloc request size 1080000000" for large table

Tags: postgresql, dijkstra, postgresql-14

Consider postgressql 14.11 (Ubuntu 14.11-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) and the following table

```
CREATE TABLE test_path (id INTEGER, source INTEGER, target INTEGER, cost NUMERIC);
INSERT INTO test_path (id, source, target, cost) VALUES (generate_series(1, 30000000),  trunc(random()*1500000), trunc(random()*1500000), random());
```

The line `SELECT * FROM pgr_dijkstra('SELECT * FROM test_path', 1, 1234);` returns

```
ERROR:  invalid memory alloc request size 1080000000
CONTEXT:  SQL function "pgr_dijkstra" statement 1
```

I tried following different solutions. In particular it seems that it is necessary to increase the value of some parameters:

- work_mem
- wal_segment_size
- max_connections
- shared_buffers
- maintenance_work_mem
- effective_cache_size
- max_wal_size

Now the query `SELECT name, setting FROM pg_settings WHERE name IN ('work_mem', 'wal_segment_size', 'max_connections', 'shared_buffers', 'maintenance_work_mem', 'effective_cache_size', 'max_wal_size');` produces the following output

| name | setting |
| --- | --- |
| effective_cache_size | 3276800 |
| maintenance_work_mem | 30000000 |
| max_connections | 100 |
| max_wal_size | 30000000 |
| shared_buffers | 3276800 |
| wal_segment_size | 16777216 |
| work_mem | 30000000 |

Maybe these settings are still too restrictive? Maybe there's a better way to use `pgr_dijkstra` on large tables?

**Update**

After many tests it seems that the problem is related to the size of the table loaded inside `pgr_dijkstra`: the query `SELECT * FROM pgr_dijkstra('SELECT * FROM test_path LIMIT 22500000', 1, 1234);` responds correctly, as well as `SELECT * FROM pgr_dijkstra('SELECT * FROM test_path LIMIT 26250000', 1, 1234);` (although obviously they become increasingly slower as the `LIMIT` increases). But for higher values, the query fails.

Comment: You ran out of RAM and might want to try to insert/select smaller chunks. Also you seem to have edited the number in the query without adapting the error message. That would confuse everyone who tries to follow the actual memory requirements.

Comment: @KlausD. You're right: I changed the query. But the error message is still the same `ERROR: invalid memory alloc request size 1080000000 CONTEXT: SQL function "pgr_dijkstra" statement 1`

Comment: Normally you don't run dijkstra on graphs with milions of nodes. How long do you expect the paths to be? if you expect paths in multiple thousands notes, then dijkstra might not be most suited. If you expect small paths (max 20-30 notes), then you might want to preselect edges in your set.

Comment: **1)** Compact the edges: if A<->B<->C, where B doesn't connect to anything else, then you can compact AB and BC to just AC. There are typically long chains of "inert" nodes like that. **2)** Remove disconnected components based on [`pgr_connectedComponents()`](https://docs.pgrouting.org/latest/en/pgr_connectedComponents.html) **3)** If that's based on a map, you'd pick `A*` over plain Dijkstra. **4)** Trim the graph similar to `A*` idea: take a straight line distance from source to target and only fetch the edges that are within that distance from the midpoint halfway